# Faking "dot" operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operators, containers

I figure this is a silly question, and there are plenty of good reasons something like this should never be considered, but let's ignore that for now...

I know that one cannot overload the "dot" operator in C++. C++ also is lacking in terms of reflective features, so providing ways to try to fake that at compile time is also tricky...

Anyway, let me now ask the question in the form of an example:

```
class Foo
{
...
public:
    int bar();
...
};

template <class T>
class Bar
{
    T* m_ptr; // perhaps use an unique_ptr for safety.
...
public:
    Bar(T* ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) { } // create a local copy instead
    int qux();
... 
}

int main()
{
    Foo quux;
    Bar corge(&quux);
    corge.bar(); // I want to do this instead of corge->bar();
    corge.qux(); // without losing this functionality!
                 // Is there a way to do such a thing?
                 // my expectations: \(^.^)/
                 // what is probably the sad truth: /(;.;)\
                 // Also, I realize there should be no good reason to do this...
                 // Just pretend I have a really really REALLY good reason to want to do this :P
                 // Thanks!! :D
}
```

Comment: Inheritance is not an option?

Comment: Is `bar(corge)`, `qux(corge)` an option?

Comment: FWIW, someone did a presentation on overloading the dot operator at BoostCon or something. It would be nice proxy types imo. FWIW, I also somehow found it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy9ITl1AWRY

Comment: But what do you expect to happen if you do `corge->bar()`?? That wouldn't compile.

Comment: There are very good reasons for wanting this. This could also be used for "reference wrappers" provided by the standard library. I figure there are many more reasons for not allowing it. Except for very few cases (`std::vector<bool>` I'm looking at you), the C++ standard committee does not take random decisions.

Comment: May I ask what is the use case?

Comment: Why not make a function in `Bar`, `int bar()` that runs `return m_ptr->bar();`

Comment: @Jefffrey In fact, the whole topic (or something quite similar) has been discussed already pre-standardization, as "Delegation" (see D&E, 12.7). IIRC it also has been brought up several times afterwards.

Comment: `Bar` is not a type.  It is a `template`.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys...

Comment: @chris that video was really interesting.

Comment: @Jefffrey I do hope that C++ includes something like this in the future. With C++17's reflective features, maybe it would be easier to fake.

Comment: @dyp That's discouraging... I guess that implies that it is unlikely for dot operator overloading to be included in the (near) future?

Comment: @kotakotakota I do not know the rationale for every dismission of a proposal regarding this; it seems though that the syntax and details are quite tricky. But there might be an underlying reason: If a language extension leads to a style of programming that the committee is trying to avoid, it will be rejected regardless of the details.